# Transformation matrix with 2 bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have the following:

$ C = ($$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  1\\
  -1
\end{array}
\right], \left[
\begin{array}
  -1\\
  2
\end{array}
\right]) ,
 B = ($$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  2\\
  1
\end{array}
\right], \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  3\\
  2
\end{array}
\right])  $ 
are bases of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( no need to prove).

$ T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ is linear transformation such that $ [T]^B _B = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  1&2\\
  -1&1
\end{array}
\right] $$  $

I need to calculate $ [T]^C _C$.

from $[T] ^B _B$ I can gather that:

$ T($$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  2\\
  1
\end{array}
\right]) = 1 * $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  2\\
  1
\end{array}
\right] - 1* $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  3\\
  2
\end{array}
\right] $

$ T($$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  3\\
  2
\end{array}
\right]) = 2 * $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  2\\
  1
\end{array}
\right] + 1* $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  3\\
  2
\end{array}
\right] $

And then I can know the values of those, but how to progress from here to find $[T]^C _C$?

Comment: Find the matrix $M$ of change of basis from $B$ to $C$, and the matrix $N$ of change of basis from $C$ to $B$ (in fact, $N=M^{-1}$). Finally, $[T]_C^C=N\cdot [T]_B^B\cdot M$.

Comment: just see the image of basis C using given transformation.

Comment: Thanks, we still did not learn that formula but were already given it in homework..
Have a good weekend!